# How do you call user input from terminal

Tags: perl, input

I have a script that starts of with asking the user for a filename.
I want to add a feature so that i can supply a filename in the commandline even before running the program.

To the point:
If i started my program with "perl wordcounter.pl text.txt",
How could i access the string after the name of the program (ie text.txt), from within the code?

I started doing something like:

```
$filename = "Filename supplied in the commandline";
if ($filename == 0) {
    print "Word frequancy counter.\nEnter the name of the file that you wish to analyze.\n";
    chomp ($filename = <STDIN>); 
}
```

Basically if no textfile was supplied at the commandline, $filename would still 0 and then it would proceed to ask for a file.

Anyone know how i can access the "Filename supplied in the commandline" in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using array @ARGV

```
  $x1 = $ARGV[0] || 'NONE';
```

Comment: Hmm tested it, and some other variations, No luck.

Comment: would you post how you tested it?

Comment: @ARGV;
$filename = $ARGV[0];
if ($filename == 0) {
 chomp ($filename = <STDIN>); 
}

Comment: change  if ($filename == 0) to if ($filename eq 'NONE' )

Comment: And what if you want a file named NONE (or 0)?  This is exactly what `undef` and `defined` are for.

Comment: if ( $#ARGV == -1 ) is another alternative

Comment: Or just `unless ( @ARGV )`

Answer (score 1):

although @ARGV is a promising option but i would rather use getopts
here is the sample code that can be used according to your need

try this **perl sample.pl -file text.txt**   and again without file argument **perl sample.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Getopt::Long;

# setup my defaults

GetOptions(
    'file=s'    => \$file,
    'help!'     => \$help,
) or die "Incorrect usage!\n";

if( $help ) {
    print "Common on, it's really not that hard.\n";
} else {
    print "reading the $name.\n";
    if ( -e $file ){
        open( DATA ,'<',$file ) or die "unable to open \$file = $file\n";
        while (<DATA>){
            print "$_\n";
        }
    } else {
        chomp ($file = <STDIN>);
        open( DATA ,'<',$file ) or die "unable to open \$file = $file\n";
        while (<DATA>){
            print "$_\n";
        }

    }
}
~
```